Why is my laptop fan spinning loudly even when CPU is cool?
I own an HP Pavilion x360 on Windows 10, and when I powered it on this morning, the fan sounded like a jet engine. I figured it just needed to be rebooted, but when I restarted my PC, it still sounded really loud.
I wondered if my core was too hot, so I checked my core temperature and it was in the 40-50 celsius range. My PC isn't being slow or anything either.
Why is my fan going nuts, and what can I do about it?

Your answer raises questions: Were you able to tell a difference between normal "fan running fast" noises and "fan is broken" noises?

I took it in to a computer repair shop and they said that the fan was noisy because something was broken inside of it.
